# Check whether element is clicked and selected before clicking next

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a menu of buttons in which users will click on one or more buttons before hitting the "done" button. However, users are currently able to click "done" without actually clicking any other buttons beforehand and therefore, can submit without actually submitting answers (i.e., an empty array is printed to the console).

I'd like to prevent users from clicking the "done" button without having submitted any answers, i.e., the array should always contain A, B, C, or D, or multiple of these letters. Instead, if users click "done" without first clicking another button, I'd like them to be presented with an error message.

I'm having trouble implementing this since I generate buttons using a map function (context: the menu displays whatever number of buttons is needed depending on myList). Does anyone have advice? Many thanks in advance!

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #done {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="done">
      <p>done</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
    let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];
    let clicked = [];

    myList.map(function(letter, index) {
      let $button = $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("buttons")
        .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
        .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
        .on("mouseenter", function() {
          $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function() {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).css("background", "transparent");
          }
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          $(this).toggleClass('selected');
          clicked = [];

          // push clicked variables to array
          let syms = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

          for (let n = 0; n < syms.length; n++) {
            if (!clicked.includes(syms[n].textContent)) {
              clicked.push(syms[n].textContent);
            }
          };

          // send data to server
          // console.log('clicked array', clicked);
        })
      $("#done").before($button);
    });

    $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

    function clearColor() {
      console.log('clicked array', clicked);

      $(".buttons").css({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      });
      $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');

      // reset clicked list after recording button selections
      clicked = [];
    }
  </script>
</body>
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) function and use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to display errors if the user has not select all the values.

Runs snippet below to see the error pop up if you have not selected `A, B, C, or D`

```js
let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];
let clicked = [];

myList.map(function(letter, index) {
  let $button = $("<div></div>")
    .addClass("buttons")
    .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
    .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).css("background", "transparent");
      }
    })
    .on("click", function() {
      $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
      clicked = [];

      // push clicked variables to array
      let syms = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

      for (let n = 0; n < syms.length; n++) {
        if (!clicked.includes(syms[n].textContent)) {
          clicked.push(syms[n].textContent);
        }
      };

      // send data to server
      // console.log('clicked array', clicked);
    })
  $("#done").before($button);
});

$("#done").on("click", clearColor);

function clearColor() {
  if (clicked.length == 4) {
    console.log('Yay! All selected');
    $('.error').html('')
  } else {
    $('.error').html('Please select A, B, C, D before clicking done')
  }

  $(".buttons").css({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  });
  $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');

  // reset clicked list after recording button selections
  clicked = [];
}
```

```css
.buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #done {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="done">
      <p>done</p>
    </div>
    <div class="error">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @psychcoder Yes! its because your the error message div is in the `buttonGallery` div. To bring the error message out and do your own styling you can put the error div just above the `</body>` -  Also, would you mind accepting my answer and upvote as well if i have helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, accidentally deleted my comment - original comment was "how can I reposition the error message in the css?" Thank you so much!

Comment: Let me update my answer to reflect that. Where do you want your message to appear ? currrently its inside the `buttonGallery`

Comment: Somewhere below the menu, outside the `buttonGallery`! I've also figured it out by editing your code to `$('#error').show()`, adding in text, and modifying the position in the css. But yes, thank you for updating your answer!

Comment: @psychcoder Here is js fiddle demo for something more nicer: https://jsfiddle.net/gx2q3j0m/2/ - Let me know. Click Done and see the error message popup in right hand corner. I am using Noty library for this. Just showing you if you want to make more nicer.

Comment: @psychcoder you are welcome glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if clicked length greater than zero

```js
function clearColor() {
      if(clicked.length ===0){ 
        alert();
        return false;
        }
      console.log('clicked array', clicked);
...
```